# Will this program terminate for every Integer?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

In a Part Test for GATE Preparation there was a question :

```
f(n):
     if n is even: f(n) = n/2
     else f(n) = f(f(n-1))
```

I answered "It will terminate for all integers", because even for negative integers, it will terminate as **Stack Overflow Error**.

But my friend disagreed saying that since this is not implemented code and just pseudocode, it will be infinite recursion in case of negative integers.

**Edit : There was a slight problem in code..**

Which answer is correct and why?

Comment: hint: what is your definition of even? For me `-2` is even too

Comment: Not specified.. But does it matter?

Comment: `if n is even: f(n) = n/2` means the program stops for even n

Comment: The only two options were if it terminates for all integers or it terminates for some integers only.

Comment: can someone please explain the downvote..

Comment: it's probably because you've asked an off-topic question (programming is off-topic here) and also it lacks details.

Comment: This isn’t suitable for Super User. I guess it has to go on [cs.se] because it’s a theoretical question.

Comment: Oh sorry.. How can I migrate this question to there?

Comment: [*How do I move my own question to another Stack Exchange site?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85017/355310) Flag the question for moderator attention, but first make sure it's suitable for the target site.

Answer (score 2):

This pseudocode **as originally given** *will* terminate for all integers. If given an odd integer, it will subtract one from it and recurse on the altered value; for even integers, it will divide by 2 ***but not recurse***. Since the function recurses with an even number as parameter when initially fed an odd number, it will only recurse once at most, and then return.

(Note: The code as originally given at the time of posting was f(x)=f(x-1) for odd x.)

As revised, it will terminate for all *non-negative* integers. However, it will ***not*** terminate for all negative integers; in particular, `f(-1)` is a nonterminating invocation.

Comment: Can you please describe using example? I am not able to understand how it will terminate for negative integers..

Comment: Sorry the question was not correct, I have changed it..